# dotnetnuke 7 redirect to gettingstarted.aspx

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've followed the dnn 7 installation videos to make a single server install. The only slight deviation I made was to create a database up front as demonstrated in the video. I'm using SQL Server Express rather than the full-fat SQL Server, but I followed the install for full fat SQL Server. I did this because I don't understand the conventional way of using SQL Sever Express, when I try to attach to the MDF file from SSMS it tells me that it's locked - even after stopping IIS!

Anyhow,  for my first installation using the dnndev.me domain everything worked great.

I then tried to repeat the installation but this time using a real domain - you can see it at www.rotherweb.co.uk. The problem is that the site always gets redirected to the page gettingstarted.aspx.

I have pasted output from Fiddler below:

## Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom

1   200 HTTP    www.rotherweb.co.uk /Home.aspx  6,839   private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:4200
2   200 HTTP    www.rotherweb.co.uk /Resources/Shared/scripts/DotNetNukeAjaxShared.js?*=1357564157543   3,393       application/x-javascript    chrome:4200

3   200 HTTP    www.rotherweb.co.uk /GettingStarted.aspx    7,793   private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:4200

4   200 HTTP    www.rotherweb.co.uk /Resources/Shared/scripts/widgets.js?*=1357564157763    3,732       application/x-javascript    chrome:4200

I have noticed that the working website for dnndev.me has sub folders of \portals\0\images , \cache, \Templates, \Users . However the failed website contains only \portals\0\cache. So this would suggest something failed during the installation but when I click to see the installation logs I get "No Installation Log"

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Rob.

Comment: Do you have any other files in the Portals/0 folder, such as portal.css?

Comment: Thanks for trying Chris. I have since deleted that website and managed to get another site built by changing the host folder of the database to the default c:\program files(x86)\Microsofoft SQL Server etc...

Comment: I'm having this issue and the only other files in Portals/0 are Awesome-Cycles-Logo.png and Logo.png. There are directories for Cache, Images, Templates, Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this by creating a database in the default folder c:\program files(x86)\Microsofoft SQL Server etc...

I'm not sure why having the db a different folder caused a problem because I had granted file permission to the folder for the account of the host app pool. If I get chance I will go back and dig a little more.